# Pascal: convert a string to some char

Tags: arrays, string, char, pascal

In pascal, how can I convert a string-var into some char-var ?  Example:

```
var Name:string;
    Arrayname:array[1..10]of char;      
...
Name:='wow';                             { I know that I write no sense things, I invent }
Arrayname[1]:=chr[1]of name;             { this command roght now !                      }
...
```

Comment: `Arrayname[1] := Name[1];` since you can access a string as being a 1 based index array of chars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the way:

```
var name:string;
begin
name:='gallo';
write(name[1]);
```

and then the output is :

```
g
```

:)